# Make HTML button appear after successful PayPal payment

Tags: javascript, css, flask, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am coding an web application which has PayPal button, HTML form and HTML button. In my web application I am using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Python Flask in the back-end.

Firstly the user of the web application is supposed to make a payment via PayPal. Secondly after the successful payment the HTML submit button appears and the user is allowed to submit the HTML form to make a database query. Thirdly the database query results are shown to the user and HTML button is supposed to disappear.

How should I make this HTML button appear and disappear correctly? I am trying to prevent that the users of my web application are not able to make my HTML button visible without paying? Are users for example able to make HTML button visible by injecting CSS or JavaScript?

I made my first version of the web application in the following way below: Firstly the HTML button is hidden (CSS) and secondly when the PayPal payment is made the JavaScript function `makeButtonVisible()` makes the HTML button visible. Thirdly the HTML button disappears when Python Flask renders the website again and shows the database query results.

**CSS**

```css
#html-button {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/payment';
var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/execute';

paypal.Button.render(
  {
    env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'
    commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button
    payment: function () {
      return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function (data) {
        return data.paymentID;
      });
    },

    onAuthorize: function (data) {
      return paypal.request
        .post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, { paymentID: data.paymentID, payerID: data.payerID })
        .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res.success);

          makeButtonVisible();

          // The payment is complete!
          // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
        });
    },
  },
  '#paypal-button',
);

function makeButtonVisible() {
  document.getElementById('html-button').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

**PYTHON FLASK**

```js
return render_template("index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

A secure design captures the payment on the server side and then allows the payer to proceed with whatever action.

You'll need two routes that return JSON, one for 'Create an Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). There is a Checkout-Python-SDK you can use.

Pair your two routes with the following front-end UI for approval: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Once capture is successful (and recorded as such in your server database before returning the success JSON to your client), there are various ways you can proceed with using JavaScript to "unhide" or display a form. Since the capture occurred on a server, you'll be able to use that fact to validate form submission against an actual payment record existing in your database, and reject it otherwise.

If possible you'll also want to update the URL so the user can refresh the page or come back to it later and still be able to submit a form for that payment.